# Add data to a seaborn jointplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I've got a nice KDE joint plot using the following seaborn method (where return and volatility are lists of floats):

```
data=pd.DataFrame({"return":returns,"volatility":volatilities,})
a=sns.jointplot(x="volatility", y="return", data=data, size=10)
```

How can I overlay specific dots on this joint plot? For example, if I'd like a red dot superimposed on the KDE chat at location (0.2,0.2)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can plot on the joint axis from the `jointplot` like this:

```
a=sns.jointplot(x="volatility", y="return", data=data, size=10)
a.ax_joint.plot([0.2],[0.2],'ro')
```

As an aside, you can also access the `x` and `y` margin subplots with

```
a.ax_marg_x
a.ax_marg_y
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to add a label to that dot? a.ax_joint.plot([0.2],[0.2],'ro', label='test') does not seem to display anything.

Comment: `a.ax_joint.text(0.2,0.2,'test')` ?