# How can a circle be drawn over a Seaborn plot?

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a Seaborn Joinplot on which I want to draw an empty circle which will mark a certain diameter around the (0,0) point. Something like this:
[image]

How can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

**`ax_joint.plot` will do the job.**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white", color_codes=True)

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

a = sns.jointplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)
a.ax_joint.plot([15],[3],'o',ms=60,mec='r',mfc='none')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

```
a = sns.jointplot(x=var_x, y=var_y, data=my_df)

a.ax_joint.plot([0],[0],'o',ms=60 , mec='r', mfc='none')
```

Comment: we posted the same thing at the same time

Comment: somehow our code look exactly the same, even the unnecessary comma at the end...(;

Comment: indeed, I followed this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33544046/5025009) to build my answer

Comment: Could you explain what ms, mec and mfc are? I have tried looking for documentation without much luck... @seralouk Thank you!

Comment: @ma7642
All three are Keyword arguments that control the Line2D properties (which is in used in pyplot;  `ms` is [marker size](https://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_markersize). `mec` is [marker edge color](https://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_markeredgecolor). `mfc` is [marker face color](https://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_markerfacecolor). You can see the description for all the rest of the kwargs in [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a dirty way to do it: generate the circle from equation and then plot that. I'm sure there are more sophisticated solutions, but I couldn't figure it out yet. This is by modifying the data of `sns.JointGrid`.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(style="ticks")

R = 8 # radius
d = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, 400) # some data to draw circle

def circle(d, r):
    # x and y from the equation of a circle
    return r*np.cos(d), r*np.sin(d)


rs = np.random.RandomState(11)
x = rs.gamma(2, size=1000)
y = -.5 * x + rs.normal(size=1000)

#graph your data
graph = sns.jointplot(x, y, kind="hex", color="#4CB391")

# creating the circle
a, b = circle(d, R)

#graphing it
graph.x = a
graph.y = b
graph.plot_joint(plt.plot)
plt.show()
```